# How to resolve error Cannot read property 'channel' of undefined

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Im getting a error `Cannot read property 'channel' of undefined` when trying to run (prefix)meme. Anybody that could help is welcome to.

```
const randomPuppy = require('random-puppy');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const Command = require('./command');


module.exports = class extends Command {
    name = 'meme';

    async execute(client, msg, ...args) { 
        const subReddits = ["dankmemes", "meme", "memes"]
        const random = subReddits[Math.floor(Math.random() * subReddits.length)]
  
        const img = await randomPuppy(random);
  
        const meme = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setImage(img)
        .setTitle(`Your meme. From r/${random}`)
        .setURL(`https://reddit.com/r/${random}`)
        .setColor("RANDOM")
  
        await msg.channel.send(meme);
    }
}
```

I don't have more details to provide.

Comment: `msg` is undefined. Simple as that.

Comment: Please make sure the parameters are correctly placed in your callback.

Comment: Do you have an index file where the command is called? That seems to be the central location of the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When accessing a property of an object, the syntax is `objA.propX`, right?
The error message is saying that `objA` is `undefined`, and you're basically doing `undefined.propX`, which it complains "Cannot read".

In this case, `msg.channel`.

Answer (score -1):

Check the arg called `msg` in the `execute` function. Maybe you forgot to pass it into the function or it is literally `undefined`.

Comment: My command-handler.js 
https://pastebin.com/qbycArbT
So Am I missing it from here?

Comment: It is `undefined`. Sorry I don't know all of your code to help check.